# Formula to Check Two Cells and Return a Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a function that will help me get these results:

```
B4  C4  D4
Yes Yes Yes
Yes No  No
No  Yes No
No  No  No
```

I need it to say Yes in the function column, only when the two in the formula both have Yes. I tried

```
=IF(B5=C5,"Yes","No")
```

but if there are two No's, then the result is Yes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the AND() function. In D4:

```
=IF(AND(B4="yes", C4="yes"), "yes", "no")
```

Comment: Thank You, However I still yet a "Yes" if there is a "No" in both columns.

Answer (score 0):

With only two cells to check, the `IF(AND(...` may be the best route but it can quickly become unwieldy if more cells in the row are going to critiqued. In those cases, I would recommend comparing the results of a `COUNTIF` against the number of values you want to return.

`=IF(COUNTIF(B4:C4, "yes")=2, "yes", "no")`

This method can be more easily expanded to include additional columns.